# May one take vitamins without a hechsher?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, medicine, hechsher-certification, issur-vheter

I.e, vitamins from big pharmacies. Are there kashrus issues? Must they be certified?

Comment: Hello michael and welcome to Mi Yodeya. This website isn't for practical advice. It happens to be I believe this question has different opinions on on the matter, and it would be best to ask your Rabbi what you should do.

Comment: This  a question for a rabbi but I will just that there are differences in opinions and it also depends on the type of vitamin and what it is being taken for

Comment: relevant: https://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/medicine/452/a-kashrus-guide-to-medications-vitamins-and-nutritional-supplements/ - https://www.cor.ca/view/689/the_kosher_status_of_vitamins_and_medicines.html

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16554/what-possible-kashrus-concerns-may-exist-with-these-vitamins?rq=1

Comment: https://www.cor.ca/view/689/the_kosher_status_of_vitamins_and_medicines.html

Comment: @robev this is not asking for personal advice.

Comment: *Lichorah* if you *pasken* you can take vitamins on Shabbos because they are not medicine then they need to be kosher and vice-versa.

Comment: From previous experience I believe that the non-active ingredients are a part of the problem.

Comment: @pcoz Another heter that can be : שלא כדרך הנאתן.

Comment: I do believe the question becomes much more straightforward when there is a doctor's order for the vitamin, and the person isn't just taking them for general health.

Comment: General health ought to be the order, "doctor" or no.  ונשמרתם.. רק חזק ואמץ.. אני ה רפאך And per R Ovadia pills on Shabbat are fine such as ibuprofen for a mild headache (rare are those who grind their own herbs).

Answer (score 0):

Per https://learn.oheltorah.com/t/prenatal-vitamins-vitamins-in-general/3299

Q: Can one assume all vitamins in general are kosher, year round, including chewable and gummies?

A: Yes.

---

IMHO that would seem to suffice for your second question.  But your first question is slightly different than this question that was phrased "Can one assume.." (i.e. in general; the product doesn't present itself as say, Bacon flavored gummy; maybe there's an issue there?).

Comment: Interesting source...in any event note that not everyone agrees.